# Is it possible use a custom cursor over a Vimeo iframe using their player.js library?

Tags: javascript, iframe, vimeo

I have built a site for our design studio that features Vimeo videos embedded with Vimeo's Player.js library. We have a big custom cursor that is meant to be used over the entire site, however obviously the cursor doesn't work over iframes.

I have used a workaround for looping videos (which don't need any user interaction) that puts an invisible pseudo-element over the player, thus allowing it to still be considered my domain.

```
.video__loop::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This page has examples of background looping videos that do not require controls, and therefore have no issues with the custom cursor:
https://www.new.company/work/two-chairs

However, I also created a custom player with a timecode and play/pause that requires user interaction, so the cursor trick doesn't work, since I need people to be able to click the Vimeo object.

This page has examples of the basic video player I made: https://www.new.company/work/nike-chantel-navarro

Is it possible to pass a click through one object to another? Or is it possible to direct a click to the Vimeo object?

According to the documentation, I should be able to use the play method as long as it's not on mobile (which I don't need to worry about since my cursor issue is not a problem there), but I wasn't able to get it to work. Currently I'm relying on direct interaction to start the video.

https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/

```
play(): Promise<void, (PasswordError|PrivacyError|Error)>
Play the video if it’s paused. Note: on iOS and some other mobile
devices, you cannot programmatically trigger play. Once the viewer
has tapped on the play button in the player, however, you will be
able to use this function.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [**plyr.io**](https://plyr.io/) player, it plays Vimeo and Youtube videos and you can use your own [CSS](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr#css).
I've tried to add your `css` to their [demo](https://plyr.io/) page and it worked fine:

```css
html, body, iframe, a, * {
  cursor: url(https://www.new.company/img/new_cursor.svg) 10 10, pointer;
  cursor: -webkit-image-set(url(https://www.new.company/img/new_cursor.svg) 1x, url(https://www.new.company/img/new_cursor@2x.svg) 2x) 0 0, pointer;
}
```

It didn't work with video ads, and this will not happen with Vimeo and Youtube because you can't play video ads along with their videos, only you can play video ads with your own hosted videos.